# Is downgrading Windows 11 22h2 or using Regedit possible to change the new UI of Windows 11 Explorer back to the earlier version?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11-v22h2

The newest Windows 11 Explorer UI isn't really handy from my perspective. Most of the time when there is a new Windows update it doesn't disrupt my work flow. But this is the first time after so many years that I’ve found the Windows 11 Explorer to be quite cluttered. At the moment, my Explorer looks like this:

[image: Current look]

However, the thing I’ve noticed is that this version of Explorer has separated the standard 6 folders from the section containing the Hard Drives. I'm used to the old UI where those are in the same window. I want to change it back to this:

[image: Previous look]

Would downgrading from the Windows 11 22H2 update to the 21H2 version make this possible? However, I have seen people online using Regedit. The steps are quite easy, because I needed to go to the directory `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions` and then add a key called `Blocked` with a string value of `{e2bf9676-5f8f-435c-97eb-11607a5bedf7}`. Will using this Regedit and adding a new key effect the OS? Or might there be an alternative solution that you could suggest?

Comment: It is NOT possible to downgrade Windows 11 22H2 to Windows 21H2 without performing a clean install. Additionally, even if you perform this clean install, you will be constantly prompted to install 22H2. Furthermore, Windows 11 21H2 will only be supported for 18 months from the point of its release and it’s already been 12 months. What you want simply isn’t possible, you can’t change File Explorer, unless there is a toggle to change the look, and in this case there isn’t

Comment: Try an Explorere replacement: https://alternativeto.net/software/windows-explorer/, https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/best-windows-file-explorer-replacements/ , and https://rigorousthemes.com/blog/best-windows-file-explorer-alternatives/ , Microsoft has made gratuitous changes to many components, such as Explorer and Start menu. Third-party replacements for these are work-arounds, unless one switches to another OS entirely (Linux, for example, gives a choice of GUI). For Start Menu, I prefer customizable Open Shell Menu, https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu/releases/tag/v4.4.170

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thanks for the links, I will check it out! But how about the Regedit method? Have you seen this before or do you know if this method is risky?

Comment: You can certainly try it. Of course, with the *next* Windows update, that might no longer work, or MS could have added another 'feature' to Explorer such as an advertising pane that you might want to remove. Third-party tools, on the other hand, are obligated to please users, or they would not be used.

Comment: Did you try Explorer Patcher? Not sure if it has that exact functionality, but if not, ou might want to ask for it on their GitHub https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher

Comment: Explorer Patcher has broken Windows 11 for some users

Comment: I don't know why my answer was downvoted as it was an accurate answer.

Answer (score -1):

> The newest Windows 11 Explorer UI isn't really handy from my
> perspective. .....   However, the thing I’ve noticed is that this
> version of Explorer has separated the standard 6 folders from the
> section containing the Hard Drives.

This is the new view of Quick Access that you are referring to with the QA content on the right Window.

This is true in Windows 11 Production and has been true in Windows 11 Insider for some time.

The new Windows File Explorer has a tabbed interface which is also new.

You should probably get used to the new File Explorer with tabs because Microsoft has made Windows so that it is not possible to retrofit.

> Will using this Regedit and adding a new key effect the OS

This is not a good idea. Registry hack likely will not work and future Windows builds may break the operating system.

At least one software product has broken Windows for some users.

Comment: Yeah I you're right. But with my last hope that I have if the Regedit method would work?

Comment: Regedit will not be a good idea and likely will not work anyway. Future builds will break registry changes